# iOS Today Extension can't build

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

I'm new for programming iOS today Extension.
When I created a new extension target, then I tried to run it.
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIYH6.png)

Xcode give errors about my container app. I tried to import all pods to Extension target but some of my pods will give error when embedded in Extension target.

Answer (score 1):

There are some APIs which are not accessible from extensions. According to this issue: https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView/issues/119, NVActivityIndicatorView uses some of those APIs internally, so it can't currently be used from an extension. If you try to add this lib to your extension, Xcode will complain that the framework is not marked as safe for extensions.

Follow the issue I linked to above and see what resolution comes out of that. In the meantime, you can try and make do with the built-in activity indicator view.

Comment: Yes, I know that the NVActivityIndicatorView  can't be used from extension, but I do not need NVActivityIndicatorView  in my Extension target, that NVActivityIndicatorView is ONLY used in my container app.

Comment: Sorry @Mike.Zhou, I didn't realize you had responded here. Ok, so you only want to link that lib to your main app. Can you explain a little more the setup of your app? Do you just have the two targets (container and extension)? Do you have any shared frameworks? Are you using any dependency managers like CocoaPods? Maybe something is linking the lib to your extension unexpectedly.

Comment: @DaveWeston Thanks for responding me. Yes I have both container and extension target. Actually I don't need any lib for my extension. I only linked all libs to my container target using CocoaPods using [target end] block. And I tried to run the extension target, but errors comes from my CONTAINER target which says that the class(from that 3rd party library) not found.

Comment: @DaveWeston you can have a look on the screenshot in my question description. But everything is good when running the container target, my extension target works well when running from container app, I just can't get console output for my extension target when debugging like this.

Comment: Ok, I'll put together a little sample app and see if I can replicate your issue.